# List Partitioning on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I want to list-partition a table on all distinct values in a column of my  MySQL table. How can I do that?

My column has 133 million entries out of which around 500 are distinct.

Comment: is this what you want to achieve? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html

Comment: Yes something like this? But this is a very tedious way.. Is there any other way since my table is very large?

Comment: `PARTITION BY LIST`.  But why?  You won't get any performance gain.

Comment: I shifted to partitioning by range. Please help me with this if you can.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938001/partitioning-syntax-error-alter-table?noredirect=1#comment46132059_28938001