# Partitioning Syntax error alter table

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I am trying to add partitions to my table. Used this syntax

```
ALTER TABLE report_datanew6 PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) ) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-06') ),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-07') ),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-08') ),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN( MAXVALUE)
);
```

It gives me a syntax error at line1.

Error : [Err] 1486 - Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed

Comment: Add the error message please.

Comment: I removed add and now its giving me this error.

Comment: I am using sql version : 5.6.17 and the official documentation says its should be poosible. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html

Comment: still giving same error.

Comment: You may have to include times in the literal timestamps: `'2014-05-06 00:00:00'` etc.

Comment: Also, what is the data type of your `timestamp` column?

Comment: Datatype is unix timestamp.. Literal timestamps also not working